# Increment and Repeat number 3 times in a incremental loop in Java Script

Tags: javascript

So the goal is to have the following:

```
k_1_1
k_1_2
k_1_3

k_2_4
k_2_5
k_2_6

k_3_7
and so on
```

What I have so far is:

But I think I'm way off....

```
while (var qi = 0; qi <= 9; qi++ ) {
  for(var ai = 0; ai <= 3; ai++ ) {
    var thisName = "k_" + ai + "_" + qi;
    var thisValue = "";
    localStorage.setItem(thisName, thisValue);
  }
}
```

Any help would be apreciated.

thanks

Comment: Change the outer `while` to a `for`, start `qi` and `ai` at 1 instead of 0. http://jsfiddle.net/6xuj402n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for two loops if you use a little ingenuity:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {

  var thisName = "k_" + (Math.floor(i/3)+1) + "_" + (i+1);

  var thisValue = "";
  localStorage.setItem(thisName, thisValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a While loop with For loop arguments. While loops keep looping *while* a condition is TRUE. Why not switch it to a For loop like so (also, your qi and ai are switched):

```
for(var qi = 1; qi <= 9; qi++ ) {
 for(var ai = 1; ai <= 3; ai++ ) {
  var thisName = "k_" + qi + "_" + ai;
  var thisValue = "";
  localStorage.setItem(thisName, thisValue);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

```
for (var ai = 1; ai <= (27) ; ai++ ) { // 27 was picked arbitrarily (3 * 9)
                                       // set to what ever upper limit you need

    // the ceiling of the current ai number divided by 3 will give you your qi
    var qi = Math.ceil((ai/3));

    //setting your values
    var thisName = "k_" + qi + "_" + ai;
    var thisValue = "";

    //reporting
    console.log(thisName, thisValue);
}
```